# What is current to-go videoconferencing software for augmented reality?

Tags: video-conferencing, augmented-reality

Probably it's possible to share your AR experience with other users.

Is there conferencing software for this use case? Or at least just stream sharing coupled with audio conferencing?

Broadcasting sender/moderator: AR mode

Participants: VR mode

More details:

- no specific OS requirement, no specific VR gadget requirement but higher resolutions are a plus.
- main must have feature: share what I see in a way people experience same in VR plus audio conferencing. Nice to have are AR inlay windows like channel chat.
- Up 5-20 members per call
- Pricing: no limitation but it must be a listing price for the mentioned 5-20 call participants.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What features do you need? What OS should it run on? Must it be [tag:gratis] – or how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions? Speaking of "conferencing": how many participants?

Comment: Hi - Did you find anything?